# Azure Kusto Query to trim multiple parts of a string

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I'm using a KQL query in Azure to create a Sentinel alert.

I can't workout how to trim a string to show the data between the third instance of the " character and the first instance of (

I've tried to use a trim_start/ trim_end and also a split command but keep getting regex problems.

An example of the string is `[ "HOSTNAME", "Test User (t.user@example.com)" ]`

I'd like to either extract Test User from the string or HOSTNAME, Test User and t.user@example.com into separate fields.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator).

for example:

```
print input = '[ "HOSTNAME", "Test User (t.user@example.com)" ]'
| parse input with * '"' host_name '"' * '"' user_name ' (' email_address ')' *
```

| input | host_name | user_name | email_address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ "HOSTNAME", "Test User (t.user@example.com)" ] | HOSTNAME | Test User | t.user@example.com |

Answer (score 0):

parse-where is good for this, too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsewhereoperator